# Vue 2 i18n localization many buttons

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, quasar, vue-i18n

I have a many buttons on main view. I want translate label when I choise language.

```
<div class="col-2">
  <localeSwitcher/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 q-pa-xs" v-for="btn in moduleButtons" :key="btn.title"
   <div class="col-12">
      <span>{{ btn.title }}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
import localeSwitcher from '../components/language/localeSwitcher.vue'

components: {localeSwitcher},
data() {
  return {
    moduleButtons: [
      {      
        title: this.$t(menu.modules.production) 
      },
      {
        title: this.$t(menu.modules.employees)
      },
      {
        title: this.$t(menu.modules.machine)
      } 
   ]
  }
}
```

'src/boot/i18n.js'

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from 'src/i18n'
export default ({ app, Vue }) => {
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en-us',
    fallbackLocale: 'de',
    messages
  })
}
```

And my localeSwitcher.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
.row-2
  .col.locale-switcher
    q-icon(name="fas fa-globe").q-mr-sm
    q-select(v-model="lang" :options="langOptions" emit-value map-options options-dense dense borderless).selectStyle
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'localeSwitcher',
  data() {
    return {
      lang: this.$i18n.locale,
      langOptions: [
        {value: 'de', label: 'Deutch'},
        {value: 'en-us', label: 'English'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  watch: {
    lang(lang) {
      console.log('%c watch: ', 'color: black; background-color: green', lang)
      this.$i18n.locale = lang
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I use $t('menu.modules.production') in HTML then q-select working but everyone button's have the same label and it's wrong. When I use {{btn.title}} doesn't work.
How can I use moduleButtons from data() to display title? Or what should I do?

............................

Comment: In your code, you put content from a variable into `$t`, i.e. `title: this.$t(menu.modules.production)` (`menu.modules.production` is a variable, not a string). But in the text, you say you put in a string `$t('menu.modules.production')`. Is that an error?

Comment: this.$t(menu.modules.production) - is an error.
I have to use '' i.e this.$t('menu.modules.production-terminal')
My buttons are rendered from data() return...
I want automaticly rendered title like buttons. One button title production, second button title employees and third button title machines.